# What are Dynamic Shadows?

Tags: terminology

The other day I was confronted by someone complaining that Watch Dogs does not have dynamic shadows. I thought Watch Dogs looked pretty good, why do you need dynamic shadows?

What are dynamic shadows and what do they look like?

Comment: Your shadow in real life is dynamic. To expand when you see people/objects in game with just a circle or ellipse around them, that's more of a static shadow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dynamic shadows are shadows that are calculated in real-time to look like the object's real shadow would, based on the shape of the object and the location of the light-source(s).

[image: dynamic shadow]

This is a computationally-expensive task, so it was not feasible in most older 3D games.  Instead, they'd precompute shadows for static (non-moving) objects, and emulate shadows for moving objects, typically using a decal painted onto the ground.

[image: precomputed shadows]
[image: shadow decal]

Since you mentioned Watch Dogs, here is a comparison of Watch Dogs with and without dynamic shadows *(please note this is an unofficial mod, so the shadows look weird sometimes)*: